# How to use token security in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

I have an Oracle database and I want to set password (Token security) for it.
Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you mean "Strong Authentication" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/network.101/b10777/authuser.htm#1006123 ?